# How to show verification code suggestion on keyboard from Message

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, ios12

I watched this video [What's New in Cocoa Touch at WWDC 2018](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/202/) and seen:

[image: What's New in Cocoa Touch]

How to show this information?

Comment: Man, this is too new to tell. What I thought was that the phone now has the intelligence and can automatically associate app name and code from messages.

Comment: @lee even i am not getting that suggestion on my iphone keyboard

Comment: set your textfield to `.oneTimeCode` and your sms message's content also need contains `OTP` string too.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Review [WWDC 2018 Session 204 - Automatic Strong Passwords and Security Code AutoFill](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/).

You will need to use a `UITextField` for entry and the system keyboard (no custom controls) and set the `textContentType` on it to `.oneTimeCode` (new in iOS 12).

```
let securityCodeTextField = UITextField()
securityCodeTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

The operating system will detect verification codes from Messages automatically (messages that contain the word "code" or "passcode") with this `UITextContentType` set.

Comment: Does text message have to be in a certain format? I have tried this in the morning an nothing showed up.

Comment: @Alix it may vary by locale, but I've found that messages like "JAL security code: XXXXXX" or "Your code is: XXXXXX" work.

Comment: I have the format like: "3456 is your verification code" do you think that is the problem

Comment: @DaNLtR it has to be specific formart. My format is verification code is: xxxx. I think word verification or security or something like that is the key

Comment: @Alix the secret is indeed "verification" - in Hebrew as well:) thanks

Comment: @Alix the work code is the main word that allows apple to identify code. the word "code" and "passcode" both works.

Also as JAL commented textContectType should be set to .oneTimeCode

Comment: Also you can do that via storyboard: Select your UITextField in storyboard/XIB and click on Attribute inspector. Then go to Text Input Traits section, in Content Type select One Time Code.

Comment: I tried different variations in Russian and it seems only : matters, but not words, so it should be kinda Ваш код подтверждения: 1234

Answer (score 12):

For those who's searching how to do that in **HTML**: need to add `autocomplete="one-time-code"` for your input field.

```
<input id="single-factor-code-text-field" autocomplete="one-time-code"/>
```

(from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element))

However, that will not work in most Android phones. For Android it's more complicated: https://web.dev/sms-otp-form/. You will need to add @domain #code to SMS text and also implement extra JS to pickup the code.

Comment: Apple’s docs seem to still say the same thing, but I was able to implement the behavior without it—or more specifically, with it set to `autocomplete"off"`.

Comment: Note that Apple is simply accepting the [specification standard autocomplete value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill). It is not anything Apple-specific.

Answer (score 5):

**Storyboard**

Select UITextField > Show the Attributes inspector > Text Input Traits > Content Type > One Time Code

[image]

Answer (score 4):

iOS supports Password AutoFill on **UITextField, UITextView, and any custom view that adopts the UITextInput protocol**. System keyboard set the textContentType on it to **.oneTimeCode**

```
singleFactorCodeTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

> Important
>
> tvOS apps can also support Password AutoFill using the same
>   content-type settings. The AutoFill QuickType bar appears above the
>   keyboard when entering passwords with an iOS device using the Control
>   Center keyboard, the Remote app, or the Continuity Keyboard. Focus is
>   also advanced to the login button when the login fields are populated.
>
> Warning
>
> If you use a custom input view for a security code input text field,
>   iOS cannot display the necessary AutoFill UI.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a website and you want to use some OTP sms authentication
you should use `code:` or `passcode:` before your OTP message.

Comment: The question is about native implementation in iOS application, not on website, but even in that case it is not clear where code (or passcode) should be added.