# What is the correct format for SMS OTP to read by my keypad? iOS

Tags: ios, sms, one-time-password, sms-verification

At first, I have a same problem as this question [How to show verification code suggestion on keyboard from Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772090), then when I received a message containing `Your one time password is 123456`, the passcode was suggested in my keypad, the case is, I don't know what is the proper format of the sms that I need to received, where can I see the certain documentation or rules and instructions for the readable sms OTP?

In my given link, they gave a video link, but for some personal reason, I can't watch it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the documentation about [password autofill](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow). It says to actually test it out yourself by sending out a text message:

> To test the format of your SMS code for different languages, text a message to yourself. If you receive a message with an underlined security code, tap on the code. If a Copy Code option appears, the system has recognized your code.

However, from other developers who have tested out it seems SMS containing these formats work fine:

> your passcode is:123456

or

> 12345 is your code to log in.

Comment: But what if I only want to receive English messages, How can I know what messages does the app will read? should I need to guess what is the accepted keywords that the app can read from SMS? so I can have a multiple choices of words.

Comment: Since apple documentation asks you to test it out on device maybe you should test it out. Maybe they say this because they are trying to improve the different scenarios of OTP text on each iteration.